# In RapidMiner Read CSV operator not assigning attribute name

Tags: rapidminer

I'm using RapidMiner Studio 5.3 with 'Read CSV' operator with 'first row as names' parameter checked. After that I can't use 'Rename' or 'Set Role' operators because "attribute name is undefined". It's like It reads fine but It doesn't send the attribute names forward.

Here's the Meta Data View of what happens with a breakpoint after the 'Read CSV' operator, where you can see that he recognizes attributes names.
[image]

Now the 'Set Role' operator can't find attribute names.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.015">
  <context>
    <input/>
   <output/>
   <macros/>
 </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_csv" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read CSV" width="90" x="179" y="75">
        <parameter key="csv_file" value="C:\Users\lffreitas\Documents\tae.csv"/>
        <list key="annotations"/>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true"  height="76" name="Set Role" width="90" x="380" y="75">
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
     <connect from_op="Read CSV" from_port="output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
     <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
     <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Any clue of what can be happening here?

Comment: It's like It does not pass the meta-data to the output.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after the CSV read, what does the example set look like?

Comment: @awchisholm I'm sorry for the delay in response. I edit the message to show images of what is happening. Thank you!

Comment: The attribute names are "a", "b", "c" and so on. The `Set Role`  operator is probably expecting a different name. The root cause is that the `Read CSV` operator is incorrectly configured. Posting the XML is likely to be the best way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Looking at it more closely, there's something about the Set Role operator that is wrong - what parameter settings have been set up for this?

Comment: I can't set any parameter in 'Set Role' operator, as long as I'm not able to choose any attribute name. Follow XML above (post edited).

I changed the names in the CSV file, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Set Role` operator doesn't have an attribute selected so it fails. Fix this by choosing the attribute name from the drop down within the parameters for this operator.

Comment: There's no attribute name to choose, that's the problem. It seems like the 'Read CSV' don't pass the attribute names to the next operator.

Comment: You can type the name of the attribute you want in the `Set Role` operator directly. The `Read CSV` operator has no meta data set in the `data set meta data information` parameter so it doesn't know how to read the data and I suppose the guesses it makes don't propagate through correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:
In the process pane, look at the *paper clip* icon on top right (number 5) and click on it...That will do the trick. Cheers; Alex

Answer (score 0):

In the process pane, look at the paper clip icon on top right (number 5) and click on it...That will do the trick. Cheers; Alex

This answer help me solve the problem. But there is still a problem,which is the "read URL" operator can't pass the attribute name to the next operator "rename operator". So there are some messages in the log. The picture shows what happens
[image].